# Page jerks on changing id in url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have page with 10 blocks each taking the height of the window. I'm trying to change the url by adding the blocks id to the url on scrolling down the page like page.com#one. The url updates fine but jerks trying to go the id. How do I transition the change smoothly without jerks?

```
    <div class="block" id="one">
        <p>....</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="two">
        <p>....</p>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
    $('.block').each(function(){
        if (
            $(this).offset().top < window.pageYOffset + 10
            && $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > window.pageYOffset + 10
          ){
             window.location.hash = $(this).attr('id');
           }
     });
```

Comment: why you do that for each `block` instead of directly point to the desired `block` with `id`?

Comment: I'm trying to change url as well by appending blocks id to the url scrolling down the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is because by setting the value of `window.location.hash`, you are telling the browser to physically jump to that element in the page.

Most likely the page you are trying to emulate does not use *real* IDs, but placeholder ones, e.g:

> http://url.com/#block-one

And has a script on page load which does something like:

```
$(function() {
    if(window.location.hash.substring(0, 7) === "#block-") {
       // Scroll to block whatever...
    }
});
```